# Speeding up while loop nested in a for loop in R

Tags: r

In R I have the following example module which repeats a for loop `n` times:

```
function(n){
#inputs - n - number of results required
    #reserve n spaces for results
    r_num_successes <- 1:n

    #start looping n times
    for(i in 1:n){

        #set first uniform "random" deviate equal to 0.05 and number of successes to 0
        current_unif <- 0.05
        num_successes <- 0

        #start while loop that updates current_unif - it runs as long as 
        #current_unif is less than 0.95, increments num_successes each loop
        while(current_unif < 0.95){

            #set current_unif to a uniform random deviate between the
            #existing current_unif and 1
            current_unif <- runif(1,current_unif)
            num_successes <- num_successes + 1
        }

        #set the i-th element of the results vector to that final num_successes
        #generated by the while loop
        r_num_successes[i] <- num_successes
    }

            #output the mean of all the successes
    return(mean(r_num_successes))
}
```

When `n` gets big, this starts to grind pretty slowly.  Is there a good way to optimise it?

Comment: Please describe in words what this function is supposed to do. It seems like you are simply taking `n` draws from a uniform sample with 5% success rate.

Comment: @Andrie Clearly he's trying to come up with a method of measuring the distribution of `runif` that's worthy of submission to thedailywtf :-)

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Ahah. And there I was, thinking this is a new entry for the most obfuscated random sampler competition...

Comment: @dplanet I see you have added comments to your code. That simply adds comments to pretty pointless code. Please describe in words what you are trying to do.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft - I lolled so +1. However, this is just a simpler example of a function I'm making which has a lot more lines, hence the need to optimise. I've commented the script - I find it hard to explain because it doesn't have any use except demonstrating my point.

Comment: @Andrie - if you're wanting me to tell you what application it has then I don't know, because I made up the code to demonstrate my problem.

Comment: OK, then tell me what the real problem is. The answer to your question is to vectorize your code. Until I understand your problem, I can't help you vectorize the code. So, although there is nothing *inherently* wrong with using `for` and `while`, it quite often signals a fundamental misunderstanding of R data structures, in particular how to perform vectorised operations.

Comment: @Andrie, the real problem is a Roulette simulation game where the current_unif would be replaced by a current_bank balance and num_successes be replaced by the number of spins.  Each time the while loop runs it checks that the gambler isn't bankrupt and hasn't won a decent amount of cash, at which point it continues, otherwise it stops.  The for loop encompasses multiple games, and what we want to do is get an output vector that is namely the "final bank balance when each game stops".  Then this can be processed to work out the win proportion etc.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's nothing you can do to significantly improve the speed of this using pure R.  Byte-compiling will give you a small improvement, but you will need to move to compiled code for any significant speed gains.

UPDATE: Here's a Rcpp solution, just for Dirk :)

```
> nCode <- '
+   int N = as<int>(n);
+   std::vector<double> rns;
+ 
+   RNGScope scope;  // Initialize Random number generator
+ 
+   for(int i=0; i<N; i++) {
+     double current_unif = 0.05;
+     double num_successes = 0;
+     while(current_unif < 0.95) {
+       current_unif = ::Rf_runif(current_unif, 1.0);
+       num_successes++;
+     }
+     rns.push_back(num_successes);
+   }
+ 
+   double mean = std::accumulate(rns.begin(), rns.end(), 0.0) / rns.size();
+   return wrap(mean);  // Return to R
+ '
>
> library(inline)
> nFunRcpp <- cxxfunction(signature(n="int"), nCode, plugin="Rcpp")
> library(compiler)
> nFunCmp <- cmpfun(nFun)
> system.time(nFun(1e5))
   user  system elapsed 
  3.100   0.000   3.098 
> system.time(nFunCmp(1e5))
   user  system elapsed 
  2.120   0.000   2.114 
> system.time(nFunRcpp(1e5))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.010   0.000   0.016
```

Comment: Holy schmoly, Josh posting an Rcpp solution?  Beyond awesome. Only meek sugesstion I have:  use `rbenchmark::benchmark()` for the timing. Oh, and maybe preallocate the vector.  But very nice use of STL to compute mean. Colour me impressed :)

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel: Thanks.  My "very nice use of STL to compute mean" was the result of searching SO. ;)  I didn't see reason to use `rbenchmark` because there's no contest in this case.  I also swiped a bit of code from your blog to get started. :)

Answer (score 2):

Just for completeness, here is what I suggested to @JoshuaUlrich:

```
R> res <- benchmark(nFun(1e5L), nFunCmp(1e5L), nFunRcpp(1e5L), nFun2Rcpp(1e5L),
+                  columns = c("test", "replications", "elapsed", "relative"),
+                  replications=10,
+                  order="relative")
R> print(res)
               test replications elapsed  relative
4 nFun2Rcpp(100000)           10   0.117   1.00000
3  nFunRcpp(100000)           10   0.122   1.04274
2   nFunCmp(100000)           10  13.845 118.33333
1      nFun(100000)           10  23.212 198.39316
R>
```

nFun2Rcpp simply adds one line:

```
rns.reserve(N);
```

and changes the assignment to

```
rns[i] = num_successes;
```

rather than using `.push_back()` which makes the memory allocation a tiny bit more efficient.

*Edit* Turns out that was inaccurate and a reflection of the *randomized* algorithm. If I add a set `set.seed()` to each, times are identical between the two C++ versions.  No measurable gain here.

Comment: You're right, it is a lot better with ratios from rbenchmark. :)