# Rcpp - speeding up random normal draws within for and while loop

Tags: r, random, while-loop, rcpp

I am new to Rcpp and exploring its applications. In particular, I am trying to speed up the following function, partly built on a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10355724/6553600):

```
code = 'NumericVector RcppFun(int N){
            NumericVector out(N);
            for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
                double V = 0;
                while( V > -1e04 && V < 1e04 ) {
                    V += R::rnorm(10, 100);
                    }
                out[i] = V;
                }
            return out;
            }'
cppFunction(code)
system.time(RcppFun(1e05))
```

The code is significantly faster than its R counterpart, but still requires some seconds to run on my computer. Given that I need to call this function several times, I was wondering if I could further improve its performance.

I was thinking that modifying the logical statement within the while loop or changing the RNG function would somehow make the function faster, but I could not figure out how.

Thank you for any suggestion!

**EDIT:** just for completeness, here is the code I wrote in C++ based on Dirk's very helpful suggestion:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppZiggurat)]]
#include <Ziggurat.h>
using namespace Rcpp;
static Ziggurat::Ziggurat::Ziggurat zigg;
// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector ZiggFun(int N){
            NumericVector out(N);
            for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
                double V = 0;
                while( V > -1e04 && V < 1e04 ) {
                    V += 10 + zigg.norm()*100;
                    }
                out[i] = V;
                }
            return out;
            }
```

Based on rbenchmark::benchmark estimations, the new code is now more than 7 times faster!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use RcppZiggurat for faster RNG draws -- I have timing comparisons in the package:

```
R> library(RcppZiggurat)
R> library(microbenchmark)
R> microbenchmark(rnorm(1e5), zrnorm(1e5))
Unit: microseconds
          expr      min       lq    mean   median       uq      max neval cld
  rnorm(1e+05) 6148.781 6169.917 6537.31 6190.073 6923.357 10166.96   100   b
 zrnorm(1e+05)  719.458  887.554 1016.03  901.182  939.652  2880.47   100  a 
R>
```

This RNG can be used in other packages at the C++ level too. It is just a header you pull in the usual way.